# How to passthrough key but only down and then up after a certain time

Tags: autohotkey

~2::
Send {2 down}
Sleep, 1000
Send {2 up}
return

This does not do what I need it to.  I could get around this by changing this to

2::
Send {3 down}
Sleep, 1000
Send {3 up}
return

but I want to use the passthrough functionality.  Is there any way to accomplish my goal similarly to the first example?

Answer (score 3):

As for your first bit of code, since you're typing `2` and your hotkey is sending `2`, you'll need to put a `$` in front of your hotkey so it doesn't fire itself.

```
$2::
Send , {2 down}
Sleep , 1000
Send , {2 up}
Return
```

The `~` is used if you don't want to block the native function of the key, which doesn't apply in this case because you're sending it in your hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

Guess the Syntax used here has a Problem and mentioning all the Actions in a Single line wouldn't work out well.

I've Worked and Tried modifying the Code and Works for me well.

```
2::
{
    Send {DOWN 2}
    Sleep, 1000
    Send {UP 3}
    Return
}
```

Let me know if you have any query in this regards.